# How to build native image with Spring Boot 3.x without Oracle Graalvm, and without oracle license

Tags: spring-boot, spring-native

As you know, Oracle has changed its license policy, so that the bill can be very aggressive for large companies.

We can use alternate free JDK for java compilation and runtime, but what about building native executables with Spring Boot 3.

afaik, buildpack use the oracle graalvm compiler, that is under oracle license.
Quarkus has alternative with mandrel.

Is Spring Boot team is proposing something to avoid the oracle license?

I've read SB documentations but didn't find mention about that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle graalvm is free for both development and production.

We are introducing a new distribution — Oracle GraalVM. It is available for JDK 17 and JDK 20 and released under the GraalVM Free Terms and Conditions (GFTC) license (also see the FAQ). This means that you can use all the greatest GraalVM features, both for development and in production, for free!

https://medium.com/graalvm/a-new-graalvm-release-and-new-free-license-4aab483692f5